# How to write headers files for a binary that's already compiled in OSX?

Tags: c, header, decompiler

If I'm missing the header files for a `.dylib/.a/.so` file, is there a way to work out what functions I could link against, and then write the header files myself?

I ask about OSX, because the tooling for object inspection is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

It was fairly simple with otool.

> [https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/CodeFootprint/Articles/MachOOverview.html#:~:text=Mach%2DO%20is%20the%20native,file%20are%20read%20into%20memory](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/CodeFootprint/Articles/MachOOverview.html#:%7E:text=Mach%2DO%20is%20the%20native,file%20are%20read%20into%20memory).

It's the `__text` section of a MachO binary keeps the linkable code.

So one can print out all of functions in a binary in OSX like so.

```
otool -t libpython3.8.a -v
```

Use `-t` for `__text` section, and `-v` to disassemble.

Will output something like

```
__PyDict_Pop:
0000000000003300    pushq   %rbp
0000000000003301    movq    %rsp, %rbp
... assembly ...
... ret value...
0000000000004614    popq    %rbp
0000000000004615    retq
0000000000004616    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

Comment: You need more reverse-engineering to be able to figure out the arguments, their types and their order.

Comment: Once you have the symbols it’s then a case of reading the assembly. No way out of that.